# Getting "The value you provided is not valid (./screenshot.png)." on importing store listing csv file in Windows Store

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-store, submission, windows-dev-center

I'm trying to import the store listing .csv file to the Windows Store, during the submission process.

I'm always getting the same error:

> The value you provided is not valid (./screen.png)

I'm uploading through the folder upload option

[Store listing submission section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mccr1.png)

[View errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsyoQ.png)

[Content of the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gukCg.png)

[.csv section of the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSwRz.png)

I've tried renaming files, changing the screenshot, changing the path of the file to folder/screen.png.

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Do you need the leading `./`? I'd guess not, or you could try backslash instead since that's the Windows path separator?

Comment: @Rup `./` or `.\ ` doesn't change the problem, the leading part is necessary, otherwise I get a "File not found" error instead

Comment: It's a known issue. Please open up a [support ticket/chat](http://aka.ms/storesupport) with our support so we can further review.